# Multiple Password Portal Page BEFORE User Account Set Up

Tags: plugins, password

I am trying to create a page that is kinda complicated. First, you need to be referred. So the first page is just a blank log in portal. You would use the referral code to log in. Each member gets their own referral code so that we can track how many members they are referring.Once you get through the referral password portal it will take you to a place to make an account. Then after you have created a password-protected account, you will be to get approval from the admin. After you're approved you can see the content and you are given your own referral code. Is this doable??? Thanks so much!

Comment: This is doable.  I built a system where one member can send out up to 25 invitations, the invitees then click a link in their email and as the page loads it checks for a myriad of things.  Similar concept but would need tons of changes.  So yes, it's doable/possible.  Best of luck.

Comment: @TonyDjukic what kinds of things does the email check for? that system might work better. Thanks

Comment: The checks are very specific to the site; checks if the invite string exists, checks if the email address of the user invited is already assigned to a user in the db, checks if the email matches the user email in the db (so people can't share invites), checks if the invite has already been accepted or if it has been rescinded, checks gender, checks age based on program restrictions, checks for exemptions to age restrictions, if there are exemptions it checks how many there are and then how many are already being used to determine if there's room for one more.  It's all very specific stuff.